# To get the sum for every 2 rows in R

Tags: r

My data has only one column. Then I need to get the sum for every two rows from the beginning. 
I have read the file by read.table function. The data looks like this

```
   V1
1  17059177
2  17059177
3  17214138
4  17214138
```

Please help. I prefer to try apply function. Thank you.

Comment: Try with `seq` to get the alternate rows

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142169/how-do-i-calculate-the-mean-of-every-nth-value-in-r-in-a-data-set-with-multiple/42142241#42142241

Comment: @BigDataScientist I'm sorry. That doesn't work, even in that post.  Error in colMeans(data[seq(1, n, 3), ]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: wrong. c&p the answer and run it. The error is produced by you. Please read some tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `rowsum` to get the sum of every 2 elements in the 'V1' column

```
rowsum(df1[,1], as.integer(gl(nrow(df1), 2, nrow(df1))))
```